# Taking Auto ScreenShot bot for Google Slides blocked content

Tags: python, screenshot, python-3.9

I've tried to build my first python script to bypass the disabled download in Google Slides.
My ideas was to create an automated bot that press right key, and screenshot every 2 seconds, saving each screenshot in a folder with a different name.

The problem is that every 2-3 seconds it screenshot the slide 2 times instead of 1.

I'm new at coding, can somebody help me?

```
import time
import pyautogui
import threading
import datetime

for i in range(400):
pyautogui.press('right')
ss = pyautogui.screenshot()
ss.save(f"SS {i}.png")
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Fix your indentation, please.

Comment: that sounds like the time between slides is just a bit higher than 2 seconds

Comment: @blackbrandt i don't understand.

Comment: @j3ser0 the lines to be contained in your for loop need to be indented by a consistent number of spaces. Because the lines are not indented, this code will not run.